# Selecting two sets of columns from a dataFrame with all rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataFrame with 28 columns (features) and 600 rows (instances). I want to select all rows, but only columns from 0-12 and 16-27. Meaning that I don't want to select columns 12-15.

I wrote the following code, but it doesn't work and throws a syntax error at `:` in `0:12` and `16:`. Can someone help me understand why?

```
X = df.iloc[:,[0:12,16:]]
```

- I know there are other ways for selecting these rows, but I am curious to learn why this one does not work, and how I should write it to work (if there is a way).

For now, I have written it is as:

```
X = df.iloc[:,0:12]
X = X + df.iloc[:,16:]
```

Which seems to return an incorrect result, because I have already treated the NaN values of `df`, but when I use this code, X includes lots of NaNs!

Thanks for your feedback in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) has these allowed inputs (from the docs):

- An integer, e.g. 5.
- A list or array of integers, e.g. [4, 3, 0].
- A slice object with ints, e.g. 1:7.
- A boolean array.
- A callable function with one argument (the calling Series or DataFrame) and that returns valid output for indexing (one of the above). This is useful in method chains, when you don’t have a reference to the calling object, but would like to base your selection on some value.

What you're passing to `iloc` in `X = df.iloc[:,[0:12,16:]]` is not a list of integers or a slice of ints, but a list of slice objects. You need to convert those slices to a list of integers, and the best way to do that is using the [`numpy.r_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) function.

```
X = df.iloc[:, np.r_[0:13, 16:28]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`np.r_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) to concatenate the slices:

```
x = df.iloc[:, np.r_[0:12,16:]]
```

Comment: It's always nice to provide the link to doc when using not so common methods ;) +1